# Create Dockerfile for python application to read InfluxDB

Tags: docker, containers, influxdb, influxdb-python

I am having a simple python script to fetch data from a table in InfluxDB installed in the local system. The deviceStatus.py script is as shown

```
import time
import sys
import influxdb
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

client = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086)
client.switch_database('deviceConfiguration')
results = client.query('SELECT (*) FROM "autogen"."FactoryConfig"')
points = results.get_points()
for point in points:
     print(point['Connection'])
```

This script runs without any error and prints the IP Address (Connection) from the table FactoryConfig.

Now I want to create a docker image out of it. I wrote a Dockerfile that looks like this

```
FROM python:3.10.0b2-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY deviceStatus.py .

RUN pip install influxdb

CMD ["python", "./deviceStatus.py"]
```

This file compiles and creates a docker image named devicestatus. Now when I try to run the image with

```
sudo docker run devicestatus
```

it shows me an error on line 8 and complains that it cannot establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

```
File "/usr/src/app/./deviceStatus.py", line 8, in <module>
    results= client.query('SELECT (*) FROM "autogen"."FactoryConfig"')
```

I suppose it’s something to do with the port. I am not able to understand how can I expose the port if this is the problem. I need help regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
SD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> client = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086)

When running in container, `localhost` means the container itself, not the host machine. So you have 2 solutions to choose:

1. Change `localhost` to the ip of your host pc.
2. When docker run, add `--net=host` to let container directly use the host network.

Comment: `--net=host` completely disables Docker networking, and you'll have trouble doing things like connecting to other containers.  [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) lists out several other alternatives.